# Setting up domain registered on Route 53 AWS for Gatsby Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, gatsby-cloud

Gatsby Cloud requires that domains have **two custom A records, and one CNAME record**.

However, **AWS does not let me add CNAME records** to a domain. I have done extensive research, but have found only dead-ends. Can I do anything to make this work or do I have to transfer to another domain service?

The domain is registered with Route 53, and has it's own Hosted Zone.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"AWS does not let me add CNAME records to a domain." is completely false. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html

AWS doesn't allow you to create CNAME records for apex domain names, only subdomains, but that is a limitation of the DNS protocol, not AWS, and you are going to run into the same issue with other DNS providers.

Looking at the [Gatsby Cloud DNS documentation](https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360063469873-Adding-a-Custom-Domain), they want you to create two A records if you are using a custom apex domain. Otherwise, if you are using a subdomain they want you to create a single CNAME record. So your statement that they want you to create both CNAME and A records is not true.